# Output row index of first element of every column in a matrix to satisfy a logical condition

Tags: r, indexing, match

I have a large matrix (8,000 x 8,000) containing numerical data. I would like an output matrix with a single row containing the row index of the first element in each column to satisfy a logical operator. Note that not all the columns will have an element satisfying the condition.

Example input:

```
    Column
Row   1         2          3          4          
 1  34.349    23.642     64.321     12.320      
 2  74.734    11.755     29.424     55.432     
 3  31.345    99.328     64.236     45.453     
 4  22.436    84.345     45.323     21.008     
 5  7.323    101.324     45.254     32.233      
 6  119.345  23.324      72.474     53.543
```

Logical operator: x > 70 gives an example output of:

```
    Column
Row   1         2          3          4
 1    2         3          6          NA
```

I'm new to R and struggled to get this output using the standard match and which functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, it is a matrix we can use `apply` with `margin = 2` (column-wise). Here we check if the column has at least one value greater than 70 and return it's index or else return NA.

```
apply(mat > 70, 2, function(x) if (any(x)) which.max(x) else NA)

#V1 V2 V3 V4 
# 2  3  6 NA
```

Ideally `apply(mat > 70, 2, which.max)` , would have given you what you need but it fails when you have no element greater than 70 hence, the check with `if` and `any` condition.

This would also work with dataframe.

---

In case there are no elements greater than 70 and column has `NA` values, it returns an error.

```
mat[1, 4] <- NA
apply(mat > 70, 2, function(x) if (any(x)) which.max(x) else NA)
```

> Error in if (any(x)) which.max(x) else NA : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

In such case, we can use `na.rm` argument in `any` to avoid this error.

```
apply(mat > 70, 2, function(x) if (any(x, na.rm = TRUE)) which.max(x) else NA)

#V1 V2 V3 V4 
# 2  3  6 NA
```

Comment: You can also you `Position` which should be faster than `which.max`

Comment: @PoGibas haven't used `Position` function before actually :)

Comment: I quickly checked with microbenchmark on 8e3x8e3 matrix, it's faster, but I don't know how it deals with not found (`NA`) values.

Comment: Hi Ronak, can the code be modified to deal with matrices containing NA values? Get following error message when applying to matrices with NA values: 'Error in if (any(x)) which.max(x) else NA: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: @Jdj67 It should still work. I just did `mat[1, 1] <- NA` to your example and it still give me the same output.

Comment: Just played around with it, the error message comes up when there are NAs in the column *and* there is no element satisfying the condition.

Comment: @Jdj67 Ohh...I see. Yeah, in that case `any` has `na.rm` parameter which can be used to ignore `NA`s. See updated answer.